# Cannot instantiate object of abstract class, but must return object of that class

Tags: c++

The requirements for this function is as:

"an addition operator that receives references to two unmodifiable Point objects and returns a Point object that holds the result of adding the coordinates of the two objects"

My Point.h

```
#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_
#include "Showable.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point : public Showable {

public:

int x;
int y;

Point();
Point(int a, int b);
ostream& display(ostream& os) const;
friend Point& operator+(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB);
friend Point& operator/(const Point& pointA, int b);


};

#endif
```

And my function is as

```
Point& operator+(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB) {

Point a; 


}
```

What im trying to do is, make a new Point object, and add the values of pointA and pointB and then return the new Point object, but it's not letting me create a new object because it's an abstract class. What can I do?

The error is "object of abstract class type "Point" is not allowed.

Edit: my Showable.h

```
#ifndef _SHOWABLE_H_
#define _SHOWABLE_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Showable { 

public:

virtual ostream& display(ostream& os) const = 0;
virtual istream& operator>>(istream& is) const = 0;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Show us the full error.

Comment: Make it a non-abstract class. And return by value, not reference.

Comment: You also should be returning by value.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The error is "object of abstract class type "Point" is not allowed.

juanchopanza I can't make it a non-abstract class, it has to be this way.

Comment: Do you have a virtual function inside `Point`?

Comment: Not related to your error but please note that names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the C++ compiler and its standard library in all contexts. Do not use them!

Comment: @0x499602D2 I don't. But it is a base class for another class

Comment: Isn't Showable an abstract class? Maybe you forgot to add virtual keyword to one of the method (e.g. display?)

Comment: @MarekRogosz Showable is an abstract class. All functions were enabled pure virtual

Comment: @MarekR Neither `virtual` nor `override` (C++11 and higher) are needed to override a virtual function (though I highly recommend them stylistically, and they can help eliminating some particularly hard to find bugs). The main problem is that the `virtual istream& operator>>` (which is also pure) is not overriden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably unrelated, but you need to return by-value:

```
Point  operator+(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB) {
//   ^ no & here
  Point a; 
  // ...
  return a;
}
```

To solve the problem about the abstract class: Look at `Showable`. It does have a pure virtual method (the methods with `=0`) that you need to implement in your class `Point`.

---

After you have shown `Showable.h`: In theory you'd now need to implement

```
virtual istream& operator>>(istream& is) const;
```

for the class `Point`, but that is weird for three reasons: The method is marked `const`, so it can not modify `Point` and it can therefore not read a value into it. Also the signature is very unusual, it means that you'd use `my_point >> is;` - whatever that is supposed to mean. Finally: If the abstract base class is called `Showable`, why does it have a method to input values? I think you might want to reconsider if `Showable` should have this `operator>>` at all or if it should be moved somewhere else.

Comment: When I get rid of the &, i get an error saying: function returning abstract class "Point" is not allowed

Comment: @user2140629 That doesn't mean adding `&` solves the problem - it creates another problem. Show us "Showable.h".

Comment: @user2140629 Updated the answer again after thinking about `Showable`'s `operator>>`, have a look if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should define all pure virtual functions of base class Showable in class Point.
2. Define the operator the following way

   const Point operator +( const Point &a, const Point &b )
   {
       return ( Point( a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y );
   }

Comment: when I tried the 2nd part, i got an error "a cast to abstract class "Point" is not allowed."

Comment: Before doing the second part you have to do the first part.

Comment: So I defined all the pure virtual functions in my Point, and the error is not loner ther! thanks

Comment: Don't return a `const Point`, just a `Point`. Otherwise you break move-semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement all of the abstract Showable class members. To do this
1) add virtual keyword to the display() method
2) implement istream& operator>>

Also, you should return Point by value instead of reference from your + operator.